# Approximation algorithm for balanced bipartite independent set?

Tags: approximation-algorithms, approximation-hardness, clique, semidefinite-programming, independent-set

**The Problem:** Given a bipartite graph $G = (L,R,E)$ with $|L|=|R|=n$, the **balanced bipartite independent set** problem asks us to output the largest vertex subsets $A\subseteq L, B\subseteq R$ of equal size (i.e. $|A| = |B|$) such that there is no edge between $A,B$. This problem is known to be NP-hard. In fact, assuming Small Set Expansion Hypothesis, no polynomial-time algorithm can approximate this problem to within a factor of $n^{1-\epsilon}$ for every constant $\epsilon > 0$ (see the result by Manurangsi: https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.03581).

**Question:** Is it possible to obtain better poly-time approximation for this problem if one is promised that the answer is $\Omega(n)$? For example, can one find a balanced independent set of size $\Omega(n^{\delta})$ for some constant $\delta > 0$?

**Context:** The reason I ask the question is because this kind of approximation is achievable for general independent set by a result of Alon and Kahale: [https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/indep7.pdf](https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/%7Enogaa/PDFS/indep7.pdf). Specifically, although the maximum independent size of a graph is NP-hard to approximate to within a factor of $O(n^{1-\epsilon})$ for any constant $\epsilon > 0$, they showed that whenever there exists an independent set of size $\Omega(n)$, one can find one of size $\Omega(n^{\delta})$ for some constant $\delta > 0$ in polynomial time. Therefore I was wondering if one can achieve the same for balanced bipartite independent set as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a nice reduction by [Chalermsook et al. (WG 2020)](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-60440-0_19) that can give the kind of approximation you want. I'll describe it below in terms of finding balanced *complete bipartite subgraph (biclique)* instead of independent set for simplicity (and consistency with the Chalermsook et al.'s paper). The two problems are equivalent.

The idea is to partition the *edges* of the input graph $G$ into $n$ disjoint matchings $E_1, \dots, E_n$. Then, we may create a graph $G_i$ for each $E_i$ by viewing each *edge* as a *vertex*, and we link two vertices $e = (u, v), e' = (u', v')$ in $G_i$ iff the edges $(u, v')$ and $(u', v)$ are present in the original graph $G$.

There are two simple observations regarding this reduction:

1. Any $k$-clique in $G_i$ corresponds to a $k$-balanced biclique.
2. Any $k$-balanced biclique has $k^2$ edges, so at least one of the partition $E_i$ must contains at least $(k^2/n)$ edges from the biclique. This means that $G_i$ contains a $(k^2/n)$-clique.

Now, if you have a $\alpha n$-balanced biclique in the original graph for some $\alpha \in (0, 1)$, 2. tells you that at least on of the $G_i$ contains $\alpha^2 n$-clique. You can then apply the algorithm from Alon-Kahale to get $n^{f(\alpha^2)}$-clique in $G_i$ (where $f$ denote the exponent guarantee by the clique algorithm, e.g. $f(\alpha^2) = \Omega(1/\alpha^2)$ in Alon-Kahale). Using 1. this then gives you $n^{f(\alpha^2)}$-balanced biclique in the original graph $G$.

Comment: This is a very nice reduction! Thank you!